# Add code chunk in Markdown, when it's another programming language

Tags: r, markdown, r-markdown

I've got this input file. And I'd like to put this as a code chunk:

```
&control
calculation = 'scf',
 prefix = 'copper',
 pseudo_dir = '/home/ccevallos/pslibrary.1.0.0/pz/PSEUDOPOTENTIALS/',
 outdir = './tmp'
 wf_collect=.true.
/

&system
ibrav = 2,
celldm(1) = 6.678,
nat = 1,
ntyp = 1,
ecutwfc = 40,
ecutrho = 300, occupations = 'smearing', smearing = 'mp',
degauss = 0.01,
/

&electrons
/

ATOMIC_SPECIES
  Cu 63.546 Cu.pz-dn-rrkjus_psl.1.0.0.UPF

ATOMIC_POSITIONS alat
Cu 0.00 0.00 0.00

K_POINTS automatic
8 8 8 1 1 1
```

If it's not possible (since it's not really a programming language, it's just how the input should be given to a program), how can I make it look like this in the html file?
[image: Python code chunk]

Comment: You can just put in into a code chunk and turn off evaluation. You can play around with different languages to get a code highlighting that looks ok, such as bash.

Comment: How do I turn it off? I'm using R-Studio BTW.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Axeman was right. This solved it:

````
```{bash, eval=FALSE}
[insert code here]
```
````

Comment: You can also accept your own answer: https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/01/06/accept-your-own-answers/